# What is the Go language garbage collection approach compared to others?

Tags: performance, garbage-collection, jvm, go

I do not know much about the Go programming language, but I have seen several claims that said Go has latency-free garbage collection, and it is much better than other garbage collectors (like JVM garbage collector). I have developed application for JVM and i know that JVM garbage collector is not latency-free (specially in large memory usage).

I was wondering, what is difference between the garbage collection approach in Go and and the others which make it latency-free?

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit:
@All I edited this question entirely, please vote to reopen this question if you find it constructive.

Comment: In Java games I would never let the garbage collector run until a suitable point in the game is reached (pause menu for example).  To achieve this I would always have some sort of manager class which keeps hold of a reference to all created objects and releases them all when the pause menu or end of level is reached.

Comment: You might like this for comparison. http://code.google.com/p/jgo/ If Go supports `struct` this has the potential to avoid GC explicitly instead of hoping the JIT will do this for you implicitly.

Comment: @JonTaylor Why did you do this? because of JVM garbage collector performance or somthing else?

Comment: @SaeedZarinfam Yes for performance, the garbage collector seriously affects frame rate and is completely unpredictable.  There is no way to tell it to specifically collect at some point other than to keep hold of all resources and release only when it is safe to do so.

Comment: @All I edited this question entirely, please vote to reopen this question if you agree.

Comment: Bump to reopen... How does Golang achieve a latency free GC?

Comment: @JonTaylor Does that actually prevent the GC from running? How does the JVM know not to just move all the objects into an extended (long-lived) object pool, similar to .NET's Gen2 collections?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go does not have latency-free garbage collection. If you can point out where those claims are, I'd like to try to correct them.

One advantage that we believe Go has over Java is that it gives you more control over memory layout. For example, a simple 2D graphics package might define:

```
type Rect struct {
    Min Point
    Max Point
}

type Point struct {
    X int
    Y int
}
```

In Go, a Rect is just four integers contiguous in memory. You can still pass &r.Max to function expecting a *Point, that's just a pointer into the middle of the Rect variable r.

In Java, the equivalent expression would be to make Rect and Point classes, in which case the Min and Max fields in Rect would be pointers to separately allocated objects. This requires more allocated objects, taking up more memory, and giving the garbage collector more to track and more to do. On the other hand, it does avoid ever needing to create a pointer to the middle of an object.

Compared to Java, then, Go gives you the programmer more control over memory layout, and you can use that control to reduce the load on the garbage collector. That can be very important in programs with large amounts of data. Control over memory layout may also be important for extracting performance from the hardware due to cache effects and such, but that's tangential to the original question.

The collector in the current Go distributions is reasonable but by no means state of the art. We have plans to spend more effort improving it over the next year or two. To be clear, 
Go's garbage collector is certainly not as good as modern Java garbage collectors, but we believe it is easier in Go to write programs that don't need as much garbage collection to begin with, so the net effect can still be that garbage collection is less of an issue in a Go program than in an equivalent Java program.

Comment: I think than this is more related to the java language than to the jvm  itself...scala, a jvm language has value classes doing a similar job http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/value-classes.html

I wish more resources comparing the jvm to the go gc, both are pretty interesting and I feel then both are surrounded by a lot of myths and misconceptions.....

Comment: @SaeedZarinfam, you may have misread it. I don't see a claim of "latency-free garbage collection" there (nor in a [quick search of its history](https://github.com/golang/go/blame/master/doc/go_faq.html#L1867)). It only says "[…] confidence that we **can implement** it with […] no **significant** latency" (emphasis added). This used to be immediately followed by a parenthetical note about the *current* implementation (the note has since been moved to it's own paragraph). To me "no significant latency" != "latency-free" and it also refers to *future* improvements.